# Как проверить значение в object JS

Tags: javascript

Мне приходит json ответ в виде object

```
data = 
    Object {
      "status": "OK",
      "content": {
        "id": "18",
        "deistv": "ok_b"
      }
    }
```

через `console.log`, если я смотрю информацию `(data.status)`, то я вижу значение `"OK"`. 
А как их можно проверить, что если `status = ОК`, то выполнять действие. 
Если я просто пишу `if (data.status=="OK")` у меня не отрабатывает это условие

Comment: `==` ................

Comment: == я пробовал тоже, просто тут по забывчивости указал один знак =

Comment: код приведенный в вопросе - синтаксически неверен. Скорее всего ты просто пытаешься получить поле у строки.

Answer (score 2):

```js
data = {
  "status": "OK",
  "content": {
    "id": "18",
    "deistv": "ok_b"
  }
};

if (data.status == 'OK')
  console.log('OK');
```